# Apex : Count the number of letters in an arbitrary string

Tags: apex, string

The String length() method return the total length of string but i need the count of characters

Example if the string is 'm*tt-', the # of characters will be 3 even though the length of string is 5

Comment: which are the characters you want to count? A to Z and 0 to 9?

Comment: i want to count A to Z

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String alphaChars = searchString.replaceAll('[^A-Za-z .]','');

Integer charLength = alphaChars.length();
```

Answer (score 2):

Another mechanism that you could consider depending on the length of your source and the memory usage of the regex replace method, could be implemented like this using `Set` collections and the `.getChars()` method on the `String` class.

```
String validCharacters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789';
List<Integer> charsToInclude = validCharacters.getChars();

String sourceString = 'I love SFSE';
List<Integer> sourceChars = sourceString.getChars();
system.debug(sourceChars);

// create a unique collection of all characters and then retain only those we desire
Set<Integer> charSet = new Set<Integer>(sourceChars);
charSet.retainAll(charsToInclude);

// output unique characters
system.debug(charSet);

// count unique characters
system.debug(charSet.size());
```

---

debug output

```
// system.debug(sourceChars);
(73, 32, 108, 111, 118, 101, 32, 83, 70, 83, ...)

// system.debug(charSet);
{69, 70, 73, 83, 101, 108, 111, 118}

// system.debug(charSet.size());
8
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try out this type of logic, it will work:

```
public Integer getCharLength(String input){
String validCharString = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
Integer count = 0;
for (integer i=0;i<input.length();i++){
if(validCharString.contains((input.mid(i,1)).toLowerCase())) {
    count++;
    }
}
return count;
}

System.debug('count=' + getCharLength('m*tt-'));
```

Comment: i have got an easier solution. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a pretty old thread, but if only do this you will achieve what you need.

```
'string'.getChars().size();
```